# Angular: should this be an invalid email address?

Tags: regex, angularjs, email, rfc822

I checked with online email validators and they claim it's incorrect format. But in angular and html5 "email" input field, it seems to be accepted:

```
email.@domain.com
```

Should our website allow a user with such an email address to create an account (where there is a trailing-period after the user handle)? Or is such an email handle invalid/impossible by RFC standards.

Comment: @PankajParkar Updated with exact questions. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt) defines the `local-part` (section 6.1) as `word *("." word)`, which means that after the dot there must be a `word`. `word` is defined (section 3.3) as `atom / quoted-string` and `atom` is `1*<any CHAR except specials, SPACE and CTLs>`, `quoted-string` is a string inside quotes.

So this clearly says that after a dot there must be something and an address of form `email.@domain.com` is in fact invalid.